# Live events not showing in YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm sending a get request to a link like this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channel_id=[MyChannelId]&type=video&eventType=live&key=[MyKey]`.

The purpose of it is to get the live events of a specific channel for which I provided its ID.

The problem is this does not work all the time.
When I go checking in YouTube, the channel is streaming, but I don't get any data through this link.

What are the possible mistakes that may cause this?
Or is it just a problem from their servers?

Is there an alternative reliable way?

Comment: i saw the permenant link for iframe
https://www.youtube.com/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL_ID/live
is there a way that is similar to this using the YouTube Player Api

Comment: alright guess nobody knows anything.. i asked a similar question at the google support forms here:
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/99528832?hl=en
if you have the same issue and its still not answered here try to see if its solved there..

Comment: You should have formulated your assertion as: ***guess nobody knows everything***. Your original assertion -- *guess nobody knows anything* --, mind you, is kind of rude; thus inappropriate on SO and also uninviting for others to bother responding to your question.

Comment: i am sorry this was not my intention however i thought that since in the official documentation they mentionted that they respond to stack overflow i thought that i will at least get some answer but that was not the case
i apologize if i was rude in anyway